# Adapting a position within a range of decimals

Tags: javascript, math

I have the following Volumes screen which successfully takes a decimal between 0 and 1, converts it to a percentage and displays it successfully on the page:

[image]

```
musicVolumeSpot.x = this.calculateXPositionBasedOnUserSetting(userSettings.volumes.musicVolume, musicVolumeBar);


calculateXPositionBasedOnUserSetting: function(currentValue, bar){

            var minPxVal = bar.x; //This is the center left position of the slider bar
            var convertedCurrentValueToPercentage = currentValue * 100;
            var calculatedPercentageValue = convertedCurrentValueToPercentage * bar.width / 100;

            return calculatedPercentageValue + minPxVal;

        }
```

This is all working correctly. And after I drag the spot it saves it back from it's position on the bar back to being a decimal.

```
musicVolumeSpot.events.onDragStop.add(this.toggleSpot, this);

toggleSpot: function(itemBeingMoved) {
                
            var volumeToDecimal = this.calculateNewDecimalBasedOnUserInteraction(itemBeingMoved);
            console.log(volumeToDecimal);
}

calculateNewDecimalBasedOnUserInteraction: function(itemBeingMoved){
//itemBeingMoved.min is the BARS far left point
//itemBeingMoved.max is the BARS far right point


            var numberOfPixelsSpotIsInSlider = itemBeingMoved.x - itemBeingMoved.min;
            var widthOfSlider = itemBeingMoved.max - itemBeingMoved.min;
            var calculatedPercentageValue = numberOfPixelsSpotIsInSlider / widthOfSlider * 100;
            
            return calculatedPercentageValue / 100;

        }
```

Now this is all fine since the decimal will reflect a decimal between 0 and 1. And a percentage directly reflect this 0% and 100%.

I wish to adapt this though for the following screen.

[image]

So now instead of a minimal decimal value of 0 it will now be 0.5.
And instead of a maximum decimal value of 1 it will now be 1.5

Please can someone help me adapt my `calculateXPositionBasedOnUserSetting` and `calculateNewDecimalBasedOnUserInteraction` methods to cater towards this? I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation `percent = (current_value - min) / (max - min)` will give a normalized value 0..1. You can use this to find the thumb position and vice versa.

```js
calculateXPositionBasedOnUserSetting = function(currentValue, bar)
{
    // Caculate the normalize value 0..1
    var pcnt = (currentValue - bar.min) / (bar.max - bar.min);
    // The position is the bar width * percent + min
    return bar.x + (bar.width * pcnt);
}

calculateNewDecimalBasedOnUserInteraction = function(position, bar) {
    var pcnt = (position - bar.x) / bar.width;
    return bar.min + ((bar.max - bar.min) * pcnt);
}

// Examples
let bar = {
  x: 200,
  width: 100,
  min: .5,
  max: 1.5
};
// Make some test cases
let r = Math.random() + 0.5
let testData = [
  {name: "Min", val: 0.5, result: null},
  {name: "Mid", val: 1, result: null},
  {name: "Max", val: 1.5, result: null},
  {name: "Rand", val: r, result: null}
];
// Run tests
console.log("Position from value:");
testData.forEach(t => {
     t.result = calculateXPositionBasedOnUserSetting(t.val, bar);
     console.log(`${t.name}: ${t.val} -> ${t.result}`);
});
console.log("Value from position:");
testData.forEach(t => {
     console.log(`${t.name}: ${t.result} -> ${calculateNewDecimalBasedOnUserInteraction(t.result, bar)} (${t.val})`);
});
```